# Badge suggestion for low-upvoted, non-accepted answerers

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I've noticed that there seem to be quite a bit of new (and even old) users who ask a question, get a good answer that gets several upvotes, and then the user either doesn't know to accept the answer and they leave, or they don't accepted it for whatever reason (even after thanking the answerer in a comment).

So I had a badge request that is basically the antithesis of the ***Unsung Hero*** badge. Basically, a user gets this badge if they have something like 15 or 20 non-accepted answers with 1+ (or x+), but less than, say 5, upvotes (and these answers are greater than 30% of their total answers and the post has less than `y` views). What I am trying to do is reward users who answer low-voting tags and non-accepting OPs, but at least have a good answer (from 2 or 3 votes)).

Some name ideas I have are: `Fortitudinous`, `Uncomplaining`, or `Accommodating`.

If you don't like this idea, (and so downvote), could you maybe explain why? I know this means you don't agree with this idea, and so I'm curious as to why. (I won't hold anything against anyone.)

Comment: Errr... [Populist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/populist)?

Comment: @michaelb958, not quite because my proposed badge has more than one but less than 5 upvotes, and the question doesn't have ANY accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already get badges for this: nice answer and good answer (if your answers *are* nice or good). I'm not sure why we need this badge.

> Hopefully this proposed badge would give users a reason to provide a good answer to newer OPs.

Why would it? It motivates them to provide answers. (If anything, ones that *won't* be accepted.) We already have other badges to motivate that.

> Some name ideas I have are: Long Sufferer, Fortitudinous, Uncomplaining, or Accommodating.

"Long sufferer"? The theme of this badge is you're providing a *lot* of answers getting a *lot* of upvotes. There isn't much suffering there!

#### We don't need an inverse unsung hero

I'm pretty sure the reason unsung hero exists is to give some acknowledgement to the people who aren't getting much response from the community - or something like that. It's a message of: "hey, we really appreciate it, but you might not feel that way, so here, have this."

The people in question here - providing a lot of upvoted answers - are *your standard user* getting an awful lot of feedback.

*Very few* people would not get this badge. Even experts like Jon Skeet and Eric Lippert would receive this badge.

### We also don't need a badge for lots of low-scoring posts

This is not an achievement, nor a behaviour to reward. If you have dozens of posts with only 1-5 upvotes, you need to work on their post quality.

Stack Exchange has a mission to create a high quality repository for knowledge. Thus we are after *quality* answers and will reward those. We are not on a mission to collect as many answers as possible, nor drown out the quality with quantity and noise, so rewarding this behaviour would do nothing short of compromise the site's mission.

Comment: I mostly meant something like for answers that have low votes and are unaccepted. I edited my post.

Comment: `If you have dozens of posts with only 1-5 upvotes, you need to work on their post quality.` Well, my thought was that some tags and questions don't get very many views, so there isn't much chance to recieve upvotes. Some questions never get more than 50 views, for instance.

Comment: @davidsbro That is Stack Overflow's problem (and it _is_ seriously a problem). The phenomenon does not exist so much on other SE sites, which would also receive this badge.

Comment: So the low-quality posts are a problem on just SO, or the low views/low upvotes problem?

Comment: The low views & low upvotes problem. All in all though, this badge would be frequently rewarding people who make dozens of crap contributions which are not good enough to get more than a single upvote but not quite bad enough to downvote. It might also reward a good answerer who's consistently answering low-view questions, but the two are indistinguishable from score alone.

Comment: I see what you mean. What about if the views of the post was taken into consideration? For example, if the post has >200 views and only one or two upvotes, it doesn't qualify, but if it has less than 200, it does?

Comment: That won't distinguish the good from the bad. Bear in mind this also doesn't care whether the answers were accepted, so we have no assurance it solved the issue from voters or the asker.

Comment: How so? Wouldn't a question with lots of views but not many upvotes be bad? Also, I was assuming if an answer had two or three upvotes it must not be wrong, and the OP might have not known to accept it.

Comment: @davidsbro Answers regularly receive an upvote or two despite not actually solving the problem very well. They just don't receive _many_, whilst the helpful answers _do_ (and then get nice/good answer badges and such).

Comment: I realize that helpful answers get more upvotes; however, there are many tags and questions that aren't viewed often. For example, I answered a question, the OP never provided any feedback, and I got 2 upvotes with 44 views. IMHO, 2 upvotes for 44 views isn't that bad. However, if I had two upvotes for 440 views, that would be different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798901/how-to-get-a-value-from-an-array-via-a-class-in-winforms-using-c-sharp/21799145#21799145